# How to modify this query shorter?

Tags: sql

How to make this SQL query shorter?

```
SELECT A.dno,
count(CASE WHEN B.state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS state1,
count(CASE WHEN B.state = 2 THEN 1 END) AS state2,
count(CASE WHEN B.state = 3 THEN 1 END) AS state3,
count(CASE WHEN B.state = 4 THEN 1 END) AS state4
FROM `tbl_drawings` AS A
LEFT JOIN `tbl_symbols` AS B
ON A.dno = B.dno
WHERE A.cMap = 1 AND B.state != 0
GROUP BY A.dno
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Try `GROUP BY A.dno` instead.

Comment: Why do you want it made shorter?

Comment: @NickW "count 4 lines" => This part seems to me to be able to shorten it with a loop, but there seems to be a way I don't know.

Comment: `loop` is a 4-letter-word we don't talk about. You want four columns in your result, you therefore need four columns your query. You could use `sum` instead of `count` - that will make it 8 characters shorter.

Comment: The left join gets automatically converted into an inner join by the predicate `B.state != 0`. The query is probably not doing what you expect.